# R ggplot annotated with atop using three values and bgroup

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath, geom-text

Is there any way to annotate a ggplot with three lines one on top of the other, while keeping the text sizes the same across the three lines?

I am almost there but the text sizes are different in the third line, it looks like the bgroup is only using the first two lines and I cannot get this right...

I am adding the text using to "atop" applications from "?plotmath", which works fine but the text in the third line comes out in a different size compared to the other two lines...

```
library(ggplot2)
line1 = "xxx data1"
line2 = "yyy data2"
line3 = "zzz data3"

df=data.frame(x=rep(1:8, 3), y=c(0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8, 8,7,6,3,2,1,3,4, 0,2,4,5,6,7,8,9), variable=c("x", "x","x","x","x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","z","z","z","z","z","z","z","z"))
p <-  ggplot(df) + theme_bw() + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, color=variable)) + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y, color=variable)) + 
geom_text(x=max(df$x), y = max(df$y), label = paste('bgroup("{", atop(atop("',line1,'","',line2,'"),"', line3,'"), "}")',sep=''), size=3.5,parse=TRUE)
```

I thought I was getting all the three lines within the bgroup, but I cannot get the paste right. If there is anything I can try please advise. Thanks very much!

Comment: share a reproducible example of your data!

Answer (score 4):

To perfectly center everything (which `\n` will not do), keep every piece of text the same size whatever the number of lines and at the same time being able to adjust the interlinear space, use this instead:

```
xlab(expression(atop(textstyle("whateverline1"),atop(textstyle("whateverline2"),atop(scriptscriptstyle(""),textstyle("whateverline3"))))))
```

Then use `labeller=label_parsed`

This also works for `facet_grid`, title and `ylab`

Note the `atop` and `textstyle` to position the text whilst keeping it all the same size and the `scriptscriptstyle("")` to control spacing between lines. You can also use varied relative sizes of text using `scriptstyle` or `scriptscriptstyle` depending on your needs and of course use `element_text(size=whatevernumber)` in the `theme` section

Comment: @user971102 I'd encourage this answer to be accepted