# Annotate ggplot plot with a multiline expression with objects?

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, plotmath

I would like to make an annotation on my ggplot with two lines, sub- and superscripts, and references to objects.

I've figured out that the `annotate()` function calls `geom_text()` which when `parse = TRUE` can use expressions from `plotmath`.

If this is my label:

```
q10 = 1.9
a = 3.9
b = -0.05

lab1 = substitute(atop(paste(Q[10], '=', q10), paste(M[O[2]], '=', a, e^(b*T))), list(q10 = q10 = 1.9, a = 3.9, b = -0.05))
```

Then it will work with base plot:

```
plot(1, 1, main = lab1)
```

[image]

But when I try to use it with `ggplot()` it throws an error:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, color = cut)) + 
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom = 'text', x = 4, y = 5000, label = lab1, parse = TRUE, color = 'blue')
```

`Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): label, colour`

I found questions related to multi-line annotations in ggplot: [R ggplot annotated with atop using three values and bgoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577023/r-ggplot-annotated-with-atop-using-three-values-and-bgoup)

and related to expressions in ggplot: [ggplot2 annotation with superscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723239/ggplot2-annotation-with-superscripts)

But I can't figure out how to combine the appropriate answers to make a working annotation. Any help from the `ggplot2` gurus out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use plotmath with ggplot, you pass it in as a string—`parse = TRUE` refers to parsing the string. Thus:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, color = cut)) + 
    geom_point() +
    annotate(geom = 'text', x = 4, y = 5000, 
             label = "atop(Q[10] == 1.9,M[O[2]] == 3.9*e^(-0.05*T))", 
             parse = TRUE, color = 'blue')
```

[image]

If you need to substitute into the string, either use `paste` or `glue::glue`.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire. For others: the final solution then is: `lab1 = paste0('atop(Q[10] ==', q10, ', M[O[2]] ==', a, '*e^(', b, '*T))')`